# NodeJS- How can I export the response data from the request?

Tags: javascript, node.js, api, request

My geocode.js class is below.

```
const request= require('postman-request')

async function geocode (address, callback){
    const url= `https://api.mapbox.com/geocoding/v5/mapbox.places/${encodeURIComponent(address)}.json?access_token=<myToken>&language=tr&limit=1`
    request({url, json:true},(error,{body})=>{
        if (error) {
            callback('Unable to connect to location services!',undefined)
        }else if (body.features.length===0) {
            callback('Unable to find the location!',undefined)
        } else {
           callback(undefined,{
               latitude: body.features[0].center[1],
               longitude: body.features[0].center[0],
               location: body.features[0].place_name
           })
        }

    })

}

module.exports= geocode;
```

My app.js is below.

```
"use strict";

const geocode = require('../src/geocode.js');

var addressArray= ["Address1", "Address2", "Address3"];

var encodingAddressArray = [];

function getGeoCode(e){
  geocode(e,(error,{latitude,longitude, location}={})=>{ 
    // Here the latitude, longitude and location fields come full
    return {
      latitude: latitude,
      longitude: longitude,
      location: location
    }
  })
}

addressArray.forEach(e => {
  // But, when I call the getGeoCode function here, it returns undefined.
  encodingAddressArray.push(getGeoCode(e))
});

console.log(encodingAddressArray)
```

The geocode.js class is called within the app.js class. My aim is to print the response data from the request that I have made with the mapbox Api in geocode.js into an array with the forEach loop in app.js.
However, when I want to print the response I called from geocode.js to the array I defined in app.js, the data comes as undefined. What should I do? Thank you.

Comment: You'll either need to rewrite your code to use the data inside the callback, or find a way to make the code async using a promise. Investigate this. callback async or promise

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in the comment, the issue is that you are using callbacks. Callbacks are notoriously hard for handling in batch, you could fix this by pushing the address to `encodingAddressArray` inside the callback, but you wouldn't have an easy way to figure out when all requests were finished.

So one way to fix this is to convert the callback to a [Promise](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Using_promises) inside the `getGeoCode` function:

```js
"use strict";

const geocode = require('../src/geocode.js');

var addressArray= ["Address1", "Address2", "Address3"];

function getGeoCode(e) {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    geocode(e, (error, {latitude,longitude, location} = {}) => {
      // Handle error
      if (error) {
        reject(error);
        return;
      }
      // All is fine, resolve the promise with results
      resolve({
        latitude: latitude,
        longitude: longitude,
        location: location
      })
    })
  }
}

// Now we can map addresses array to an array of promises and then work with results:
Promise.all(addressArray.map(e => getGeoCode(e)))
  // Here it is guaranteed that all promises are resolved
  .then((encodingAddressArray) => console.log(encodingAddressArray))
```

As further improvement, consider replacing `postman-request` library with some more modern, promise based alternative like [node-fetch](https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-fetch), [got](https://www.npmjs.com/package/got), or [axios](https://www.npmjs.com/package/axios). This way you won't need to wrap the results into promise yourself. Once you switch to promises, you can also simplify the code using [async / await](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/async_function).